# Random error when I start Guard with Spork

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, guard, spork

I'm trying to use Spork + Guard + Rspec but, obviously it fails.

my gemfile :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.2'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '>= 2.14'
  # guard
  gem 'guard-rspec', '2.5.0'
  # spork
  gem 'spork-rails', '4.0.0'
  gem 'guard-spork', '1.5.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

my Guardfile :

```
# A sample Guardfile
# More info at https://github.com/guard/guard#readme

guard 'spork', :cucumber_env => { 'RAILS_ENV' => 'test' }, :rspec_env => { 'RAILS_ENV' => 'test' } do
  watch('config/application.rb')
  watch('config/environment.rb')
  watch('config/environments/test.rb')
  watch(%r{^config/initializers/.+\.rb$})
  watch('Gemfile.lock')
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb') { :rspec }
  watch('test/test_helper.rb') { :test_unit }
  watch(%r{features/support/}) { :cucumber }
end


guard 'rspec', all_after_pass: false, cli: '--drb' do
  watch(%r{^spec/.+_spec\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$})     { |m| "spec/lib/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb')  { "spec" }

  # Rails example
  watch(%r{^app/(.+)\.rb$})                           { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/(.*)(\.erb|\.haml)$})                 { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}#{m[2]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)_(controller)\.rb$})  { |m| ["spec/routing/#{m[1]}_routing_spec.rb", "spec/#{m[2]}s/#{m[1]}_#{m[2]}_spec.rb", "spec/acceptance/#{m[1]}_spec.rb"] }
  watch(%r{^spec/support/(.+)\.rb$})                  { "spec" }
  watch('config/routes.rb')                           { "spec/routing" }
  watch('app/controllers/application_controller.rb')  { "spec/controllers" }

  # Capybara features specs
  watch(%r{^app/views/(.+)/.*\.(erb|haml)$})          { |m| "spec/features/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }

  # Turnip features and steps
  watch(%r{^spec/acceptance/(.+)\.feature$})
  watch(%r{^spec/acceptance/steps/(.+)_steps\.rb$})   { |m| Dir[File.join("**/#{m[1]}.feature")][0] || 'spec/acceptance' }
end
```

my spec_helper :

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'spork'


Spork.prefork do
  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
  require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
  require 'rspec/rails'
  require 'rspec/autorun'


  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}


  ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending! if defined?(ActiveRecord::Migration)

  RSpec.configure do |config|


    # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
    config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"


    config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

    config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

    config.order = "random"
    config.include Capybara::DSL
  end
end

Spork.each_run do
  # This code will be run each time you run your specs.

end


﻿# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

# Checks for pending migrations before tests are run.
# If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove this line.
ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending! if defined?(ActiveRecord::Migration)

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ## Mock Framework
  #
  # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
  #
  # config.mock_with :mocha
  # config.mock_with :flexmock
  # config.mock_with :rr

  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
  # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
  # rspec-rails.
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #     --seed 1234
  config.order = "random"
  config.include Capybara::DSL
end
```

I did all the configuration :

```
bundle exec guard init rspec
bundle exec spork --bootstrap
bundle exec guard init spork
```

And when I try `bundle exec guard` a wtf-error appears (I didn't copy all, because it's too wtf, just the beginning) :

```
C:/Users/Leo/Dropbox/Rails_projCe:c/tUss/esrasm/pLleeo_/aDprpo/psbpoexc//Rsapielcs__hperlopjeerc.trsb/:s8a8m:pilne _`a<ptpo/ps p(erce/qsupierce_dh)e>l'pe:r .urnbd:e8f8i:niend  `l<otcoapl  v(arrieabqluei roerd )m>e'tho:d  `uïn»d¿e'f ifonre mda inl:oObcjaeclt  v(NaarmeiEarbrolre)
r        fmreotmh oCd: /`Rïa»i¿l'sI nfsotra lmlaeirn/:ROubbjye2c.0t.0 /(liNba/mreuEbryr/goemrs/)2.
.0      /fgermos/ma ctCi:ve/sRupapiolrstI-n4s.t0a.l2l/elirb//Raucbtyi2v.e0_.s0u/plpiobr/tr/duebpye/ngdeemnsc/i2e.s0..r0b/:g2e23m:sin/ a`lcotadi'v
e       sfruopm pCo:/rRtai-l4s.I0n.s2t/allilebr//aRucbtyi2.v0e._0s/ulpipbo/rrtu/bdye/pgeenmsd/e2n.c0i.e0s/.grebm:s2/2a3c:tiivne su`plpoorat-d4'.0
2/l     ifbr/aocmti vCe_:s/uRpapiolrstI/ndsetpaelnldeern/cRiuebsy.2r.b0:.202/3l:iinb /`rbulboyc/kg eimns /l2o.a0d.'0
/       gferomms C/:a/RcatilisvInesstuaplploerrt/-R4u.b0y.22./0.l0i/bl/iabc/triuvbey_/sguepmps/o2r.t0./0d/geepmse/nacdteivnecsuipeposr.t-r4b.:02.223/:liinb /`abcltoicvke _isnu plpooardt'/d
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found !

I replaced my Gemfile by this one https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_rails_4/blob/master/Gemfile and my spec_helper by this one https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_rails_4/blob/master/spec/spec_helper.rb